# Difference between redirect object and res.redirect in Next.js

Tags: next.js

What is the difference in Next.js between

```
return {
  redirect: {
    permanent: false,
    destination: ''
  }
};
```

And

```
res.redirect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, they achieve the same goal but are used in different contexts.

##### #1 Using `redirect` object in `getServerSideProps`

Returning a `redirect` object from `getServerSideProps` is essentially a more idiomatic and valid way of redirecting to another path from within that function. From the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#redirect):

> The `redirect` object allows redirecting to internal and external
> resources. It should match the shape of `{ destination: string, permanent: boolean }`. In some rare cases, you might need to assign a
> custom status code for older `HTTP` clients to properly redirect. In
> these cases, you can use the `statusCode` property instead of the
> `permanent` property, but not both.

It ends up (roughly) executing the following code internally:

```js
res.statusCode = 307
res.setHeader('Location', '/')
res.end()
```

In your first code block the redirect will be executed with status code `307`, due to the `permanent: false` value.

##### #2 Using `res.redirect()` in API routes

In Next.js, the `res.redirect()` method can be used within API routes to redirect to the specified path. From the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/response-helpers):

> `res.redirect([status,] path)` - Redirects to a specified path or URL.
> `status` must be a valid [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). If not specified, `status`
> defaults to "307" "Temporary redirect".

It can be used as follows, where a status code and path are passed to it:

```js
res.redirect(307, '/')
```

Comment: Thanx, So they are mostly the same because I prefer Temporary redirect.